# make_unique how pass complex type as ctor parameter?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Given the code below:

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::tuple<int, int> param)
    : mytuple(param){}

tuple<int, int> mt = { 1,2 };
auto myClass = make_unique<MyClass>(mt); // ok
auto myClass1 = make_unique<MyClass>({1,2}); // error
auto myClass01 = make_unique<MyClass>(make_tuple(1,2)); // ok
unique_ptr<MyClass> Myclass2(new MyClass({ 1,2 })); // ok
```

I get errors:

> Error C2660   'std::make_unique': function does not take 1 arguments
>
> Error (active)    E0304   no instance of overloaded function "make_unique"
>   matches the argument list

Why is this happening and what I should do?

Comment: `{1, 2}` has no type and cannot be deduced for `T&&`.

Comment: *"What should I do?"* It's not getting any better than `make_unique<MyClass>(make_tuple(1,2));`.

Comment: What you should do first is post a complete example, see [mcve]. We can guess what the `MyClass` constructor looks like, but it would be good to have it in the code snippet.

Comment: "what I should do?" edit your question to contain [mcve]